# Why is analysis over the complex numbers so useful vs say other fields?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis, field-theory, intuition

First I'll state a statement that I hope is false, but I do not know if it is:
"Complex analysis is used a lot compared to analysis over other fields (as in it gives a lot of results like the prime number theorem and such that other fields don't)."

If my statement isn't true, can you provide examples of extraordinary results of analysis over other fields?

If it is, why is it that complex numbers give those results and other fields don't?

My guess is that it's the only algebric closure of R, but why is that important for deriving theorems in number theory?

Comment: speak to any information-theorist or cryptographer, and they'll disagree and say that finite fields are the most useful sorts of fields. What do you mean by "extraordinary results of analysis", is it just important results involving other fields, or do you refer to a specific style/flavor of result (like those of real analysis).

Comment: @frogeyedpeas Ok I'll be more specific, results about number theory. Almost all the theorems I met on wikipedia on number theory that were proved with analysis were proved with complex analysis.

Comment: First off you only want to do "analysis" over a complete field, so there aren't a whole lot of choices, you have $\Bbb R$, $\Bbb C$ and you have the completions of the $p$-adic fields.  What other fields did you have in mind?

Comment: I think [p-adic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/P-adic_number) is a good example for this question.

Comment: @GregoryGrant p-adic fields, what are some theorems that arise from analysis over there?

Comment: I'm not a big expert on the completions of the p-adic fields, they are complicated because you start with $\Bbb Q$ like usual, and complete with respect to the p-adic norm and then you take the algebraic closure.  With the normal absolute value you'd be done, now you'd have something both complete and algebraically complete.  But with the p-adics after you complete and then algebraically complete it's no longer complete so you have to complete again.  --> continued in next message

Comment: And then you may have to algebraically close again.  But around this point you do get a complete and algebraically complete field, I think they call it Omega sub $p$ or something like that.  It's a big moster of a field and yet people do do analysis there.

Comment: With the usual metric, $\mathbb C$ is a connected, path-connected, locally compact, $\sigma$-locally compact , separable complete metric space. Many  results in complex analysis use some of these properties.   $\mathbb C$  can be shown to be algebraically complete by entirely elementary means  by using  them .

Comment: One can do analysis over any complete $p$-adic field. The most informative proof of the analytic continuation and functional equation of the Riemann zeta function involves doing analysis over the Adele ring $\mathbb A_\mathbb Q$, which is essentially a product of $p$-adic fields. (This was the content of Tate's thesis.) This and similar results underpin a lot of number theory - one can't even state the Riemann hypothesis without knowing that the zeta function can be analytically continued.